# Unhandled Exception: FormatException: not a valid link-local address but contains %

Tags: flutter, dart

I wrote a test function which allows me to test a link and toasts me a toast if the server responds. I do the test using the http library. At first, everything was fine, but from the day my SDK crashed (but I was able to restore it by following the instructions given by the android studio idea). After this incident, when I compile my application and test my link again I get a Format Exception error. When I print the field retrieved by my editingController, it is exactly the same as the one entered. And when I click on the button test% 20 is added at the end of my field I don't know why, it makes my link invalid. What to do ?

The link entered in my field is test.sellams.com

```
E/flutter (11454): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: test.sellams.com%20 is not a valid link-local address but contains %. Scope id should be used as part of link-local address. (at character 17)
E/flutter (11454): test.sellams.com%20
```

my link test function

```
ToastLink() async {
          try {
            _checkInternetConnection();
            Map result;
          String  url = linkController.text;
          print(url);
          String link ="http://"+url;
            http.Response response = await http.post(
                link);
           // result = json.decode(response.body);
              final int statusCode = response.statusCode;
              if (statusCode == 200) {
                Fluttertoast.showToast(
                    msg: " CE LIEN EST VALIDE ",
                    toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                    textColor: Colors.white
                );
                setState(() {
                  SaveUrlPreferences(url);
                });


              }
              else{
                Fluttertoast.showToast(
                    msg: " CE LIEN EST INVALIDE ",
                    toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                    textColor: Colors.white);


                 // Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 2000));
              }
```

the link field

```
 new TextField(
               controller: linkController,
               focusNode: myFocusNodeLink,
               textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
               onSubmitted: (term) {
                 _fieldFocusChange(context, myFocusNodeLink, myFocusNodeUserName);
               },
               decoration: InputDecoration(
                 errorText: _validate ? 'Le champ lien est obligatoire' : null,
                 hintText: "Entrez le lien",
                 hintStyle: TextStyle(
                   color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                   fontSize: 16.0,
                 ),
                 border: OutlineInputBorder(
                   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                 ),
                 prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.attachment),
               ),
             ),
             SizedBox(height: 15.0,),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the following line:

String link ="http://"+url.trim();